# Anugularjs filter in 2 level of repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a ngRepeat inside a ngRepeat and I want to filter both.
The filter should match either name of folder or name of the form, right now the filter is working but it is checking all the properties.
I want the filter to check only the "Name" property for the folder and the form.

Here is a plunker: plnkr.co/edit/Y5HXbtAB3S7KxGqchQZm?p=preview

Comment: here's plunk https://plnkr.co/edit/Y5HXbtAB3S7KxGqchQZm?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would recommend changing the folder "Name" property to something like "folderName" in order to prevent confusion with the forms "Name" property.

If I understand correctly you want the folder to show in 2 cases:

1. One of the forms name matches the search.
2. The folder name itself matches the search (show all the children as well).

UPDATE:

For what you wanted I preferred to use a custom function the manipulates the shown array instead of using the filter, check out this code.

```js
// Code goes here
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("ctrl",function($scope){

  var folder = [
  {
    "DisplayName_MO": "Templates",
    "Key": 555974658,
    "folderName": "Templates",
    "forms": [
      {
        "Key": 751017984,
        "Revision": 2,
        "Name": "form1"
      },
      {
        "Key": 751017985,
        "Revision": 2,
        "Name": "form2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "DisplayName_MO": "Archive",
    "Key": 555974659,
    "folderName": "Archive",
    "forms": [
      {
        "Key": 751017986,
        "Revision": 2,
        "Name": "trex"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "DisplayName_MO": "Inbox",
    "Key": 555974660,
    "folderName": "Inbox",
    "forms": [
      {
        "Key": 751017987,
        "Revision": 2,
        "Name": "View"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "DisplayName_MO": "Outbox",
    "Key": 555974661,
    "folderName": "Outbox",
    "forms": [
      {
        "Key": 751017988,
        "Revision": 2,
        "Name": "Star"
      }
    ]
  }
]

  $scope.updateFilteredArray = function(){
  var tempArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(folder)), //create a deep copy of the originl array
    searchTerm = $scope.searchText;
    if(searchTerm){
    searchTerm = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
       for(var i = 0; i < tempArray.length; i++){
        if(tempArray[i].folderName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) == -1){
          var formsArray = tempArray[i].forms;
          for(var y = 0; y < formsArray.length; y++){
            if(formsArray[y].Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) == -1){
              formsArray.splice(y, 1);
              y--;
            }
          }
          if(formsArray.length == 0){
            tempArray.splice(i, 1);
            i--;
          }
        }
       }
    }
    $scope.filteredArray = tempArray;
  }

  $scope.filteredArray = folder;
  
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.6.2" data-semver="1.6.2" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.2/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="ctrl">
      
      <input ng-model="searchText" ng-change="updateFilteredArray()"/>
      
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in filteredArray">
          {{x.folderName}}
          <ul><li ng-repeat="y in x.forms">{{y.Name}}</li></ul>
          
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: when searching on folder level it should give folder as well as form , right now e.g if you search 'templates' it is not showing the form names

Comment: so just to clarify, when there is a match at the folder level all children should be shown? even if none of the children match the search term?

Comment: yes if  there is a match at the folder level all children should be shown .